# code setOnClickListener for multiple TextViews

Tags: android

I have 40+ `TextViews` and I want to add `click` events on them, but I try to do it "shortly" :

```
final GridLayout myGL;
myGL = (GridLayout) v0725.findViewById( R.id.tab1 );
for(  int i = 0; i < myGL.getChildCount(); i++ )
      if ( getResources().getResourceEntryName(((TextView) myGL.getChildAt(i)).getId()).indexOf("v")==0 ) {
          ((TextView) myGL.getChildAt(i)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.v("edf", getResources().getResourceEntryName(((TextView) myGL.getChildAt(i)).getId()));

        }
    });
};
```

But Eclipse stops me on the `Log.v` line, because `i` should be final (but I can't)
any tips?

Comment: if you used `GridView`, you should use an `Adapter` ... example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Answer (score 1):

your Activity must implements:

```
public class YourActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

and you must override mwthod onClick(View view):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   Log.v("edf", getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId())); 
}
```

and your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myGL.getChildCount(); i++) {
  if (getResources().getResourceEntryName(((TextView) myGL.getChildAt(i)).getId()).indexOf("v")==0 ) {
       myGL.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do it. Disregard my answer, since it only deals with the technicality of passing a variable value to an anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the field final so that the compiler has a guarantee that the value does not change during the lifetime of the anonymous inner class. Since i is used as a loop counter it is pretty sure that the value will change.

So you need to copy the value of i to a variable marked final.

```
for(  int i = 0; i < myGL.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
    final int j = i;
    ...
             Log.v("edf", getResources().getResourceEntryName(((TextView) myGL.getChildAt(j)).getId()));

}
```